# AEM 6.4 [coral-3] – Toggle dialog fields based on dropdown selection - Doesn’t work for multiple values

Tags: aem

In AEM 6.4 [coral-3], we could implement toggling of dialog fields based on the dropdown selection by adding granite:data node and granite:class. But this works only for single value. How to make it work for multiple values. For example, if a dropdown has three values [x, y, z] then I would like to show "text1" if we select x OR y and would like to show "text2" if we select z. I have tried making showhidetargetvalue to String[] with multiple values [x, y], but it didn’t work. Any reference will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of showhidetargetvalue doesn't support multiple values, the code for the default implementation of this feature can be found in:

`/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/dropdownshowhide/clientlibs/dropdownshowhide.js`

unfortunately you will have to create a customised version of this script to support it.